# SQL expand row mapping every grouped value to a coordinated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, where I'm doing some iterative calculations for an engineering application. ColD has been calculated from another query, so it's basically trying to find a best fit. Part of the strategy in the best fit, is to get a point where I look at each grouping of ColC (grouping signified by ColB), and have each value reference the value in ColD.

In essence, I need Table A to be converted to Table B

Table A:

```
ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD
1      1      A      200
2      2      B      300
3      3      C      400
4      1      X      200
5      2      Y      400
6      3      Z      600
```

Table B:

```
A   200
B   200
C   200
A   300
B   300
C   300
A   400
B   400
C   400
X   200
Y   200
Z   200
X   400
Y   400
Z   400
X   600
Y   600
Z   600
```

Comment: how should you classify rows to a group? it is not clear from the question.

Comment: Isn't it obvious from looking at colB? Or should I make another column that helps with the grouping? In the example above, A,B,C is one group, X,Y,Z is another. Right now I'm showing the state of the current table.

Comment: it is obvious to you .. not to the one reading it for the first time. you should atleast specify how to get a group out of those rows.

Comment: ColB is repeating, it goes back to 1 each time to signify the beginning of another group.

Comment: But your question is leading me to a new clue, I should make a new column to signify the groupings, hopefully I can see where that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        ColA
        , ColB
        , ColC
        , ColD
        , SUM(CASE WHEN L < ColB THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ColA) GroupID
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ColA
                , ColB
                , ColC
                , ColD
                , LAG(ColB, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ColA) L
            FROM YourTable
        ) Q
)

SELECT
    C1.ColC
    , C2.ColD
FROM
    cte C1
    JOIN cte C2 ON C1.GroupID = C2.GroupID
ORDER BY C2.ColA
```

Comment: WOW! You got it, that was fast! There are expressions in here I've never seen, you got the group id, which was what I was missing, and you were able to join onto itself. I was almost there, but you do it before I did.